# Python + C# - возможно ли? Можно ли использовать numpy из C#

Tags: c#, python, numpy

Здравствуйте!

У меня возникла ситуация, в которой мне необходимо использовать методы, аналогичные методам из Python'овской библиотеки Numpy(для работы с матрицами) в проекте на С#, но похожего ничего для шарпа я не нашел, и, внимание, вопрос - возможно ли как нибудь подключить и использовать Numpy в проекте на C#? Или может быть есть какие нибудь альтернативные решения?

Comment: Не устаю поражаться, как плохо у людей с поисковой деятельностью. Результат с первой страницы гугла - [NumPy and SciPy for IronPython / .Net](http://blog.enthought.com/python/scipy-for-net/#.Wca9sbKrSUk).

Comment: вроде, плюсы и питон активно юзаются вместе. даж не знаю, спрячьте нампай внутри проекта на си и когда надо дергаете его

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev наличие ссылки от 2011 года, которая заявляет  о выполнении монументальной работы по адаптации numpy, cython для .NET, ничего не говорит как такие задачи сегодня выполняются, не содержит практический пример кода и практические подсказки от обычных людей, которые пробовали технологию.  Возможность опубликовать/обновить свой ответ, комментировать, голосовать за разные ответы, закрывать вопросы как дубликаты, чтобы разные поисковые слова в одно место вели не присутствует в Гугле. *Stack Overflow это место назначения куда Гугл посылает*

Comment: @jfs поэтому я и написал ссылку комментарием, а не ответом. Вы можете дать ответ лучше.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ссылка безусловно полезная. Но кроме ссылки, ваш комментарий может создать впечатление что если что-то можно найти по вопросу на первой странице результатов в гугле, то не следует задавать вопрос на stack overflow. Это не так.

Comment: Опишите какие возможности вам нужны для тех кто не знаком с питоном, но знаком с шарпом

Comment: Есть, например, такой проект: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ пробовали его? Каких возможностей не хватило?